# Ionic v4 "Deploy" update - white screen after installation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to set up my Ionic application to use the Ionic Pro "Deploy" update service, but it's hanging when the update is actually installed and the app tries to reload.

I have a basic app installed on my Android 8.0 tablet, and a slightly updated version of the app pushed to the Ionic Pro deploy service. I can see this update on the Ionic Pro dashboard. My app can see the update, download it, and extract it.

But as soon as I trigger the "reloadApp()" function, it shows me a white screen and the app doesn't load. There are no errors appearing on the console in Chrome's remote device tools. The console says that the "Ionic Native: deviceready" event fired, but then nothing else. This is true even if I force-close and reload the application entirely - the update process breaks the app, and requires a full reinstall.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Ionic v4 (beta) apps are currently not officially supported by Ionic Pro. You can see an article about this on their zendesk (need to register to view) https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008696153-2018-08-29-Status-of-Ionic-v4-support-in-Ionic-Pro

As mentioned in the link, the issue you're having *could* be fixed by doing the following, but would not recommend doing this on a production app:

```
Users are welcome to test Deploy with v4 apps on non-production projects.
If you wish to test live updates, you will need to manually add cordova.js to index.html in your src directory:
<!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

There is also an open issue on their repo: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic/issues/150

Comment: I was aware of that, and I have included the cordova.js script tag in my index.html page.

Without it my app warns that cordova-plugin-ionic is not installed. When I do include it, my app gets to a white page, the console reports that Ionic fired the deviceready event, but nothing actually happens after that - no HTML is loaded, nothing is displayed to the user.

It seems that script tag is not the solution for this issue.